# A Collection isn't Arrayable when testing

Tags: laravel

I'm making some HTTP Tests and I'm having an issue in one of them. Here's what happening:

- Same endpoint
- Same data on database
- Same PHP version
- Same headers
- Different results

Here's the code:

1.

```
dd(
    $interestResults instanceof Arrayable,
    get_class($interestResults),
    $interestResults[0] instanceof Arrayable,
    get_class($interestResults[0]),
    Arrayable::class,
    phpversion()
);
```

2.

```
$typeBefore = gettype($interestResults);
$typeOfItemBefore = gettype($interestResults[0]);
$interestResults = $interestResults->toArray();
dd($typeBefore, $typeOfItemBefore, gettype($interestResults), gettype($interestResults[0]));
```

Here's what I get on Postman:

1.

```
true
"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection"
true
"App\Post"
"Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable"
"7.2.4"
```

2.

```
"object"
"object"
"array"
"array"
```

Here's what I get when testing:

1.

```
false
"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection"
true
"App\Post"
"Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable"
"7.2.4"
```

2.

```
"object"
"object"
"array"
"object"
```

Comment: I'd open an issue cross-posting from phpunit and laravel repositories.

Comment: @SparK Yeah, it looks like a laravel testsuite bug. I don't think phpunit has anything to do with it. I'm still debugging it and if I find any solution I will make a PR to laravel/framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

If you use [Laravel Valet](https://github.com/laravel/valet), don't use your global phpunit. **Use the project's local phpunit** by running `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

### Detailed version

While investigating this strange behavior I came to the conclusion that, since I know that class **IS** `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and it extends `Illuminate\Support\Collection` that implements `Arrayable`, it couldn't just "don't be" an instance of `Arrayable`.

So I've decided to check with Reflection what kind of `Arrayable` it was. That was my code:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($interestResults));
$implementedInterfacesList = array_keys($reflection->getInterfaces());
$isItArrayableByReflaction = in_array('Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable', $implementedInterfacesList);
$isItArrayableByInstanceOf = $interestResults instanceof \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
dd($implementedInterfacesList, $isItArrayableByReflaction, $isItArrayableByInstanceOf);
```

And, for my surprise, those were the results:

**Postman**

```
array:8 [
    0 => "JsonSerializable"
    1 => "Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable"
    2 => "Traversable"
    3 => "IteratorAggregate"
    4 => "Countable"
    5 => "Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable"
    6 => "ArrayAccess"
    7 => "Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection"
]
true
true
```

**Terminal**

```
array:8 [
    0 => "JsonSerializable"
    1 => "Tightenco\Collect\Contracts\Support\Jsonable"
    2 => "Traversable"
    3 => "IteratorAggregate"
    4 => "Countable"
    5 => "Tightenco\Collect\Contracts\Support\Arrayable"
    6 => "ArrayAccess"
    7 => "Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection"
]
false
false
```

Interesting, `Tightenco\Collect\Contracts\Support\Arrayable`, but <s>composer</s> why tightenco\collect?

```
composer why tightenco/collect

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package "tightenco/collect" in your project
```

So, the error isn't on my project neither on its dependencies. I've tried to run local local phpunit (`vendor/bin/phpunit`) and:

```
array:8 [
    ...
]
true
true
```

Great! Problem "fixed", but <s>composer</s> why was it happening?

```
composer global why tightenco/collect
Changed current directory to /Users/guilherme/.composer
laravel/valet  v2.0.10  requires  tightenco/collect (^5.3)
```

That's it! When running my global phpunit composer will use my global autoload and [Laravel conflicts with tightenco/collect](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/composer.json#L73).

### The *solution*?

Well, while I don't consider it a solution, I think this is the official one: **Use the project's local phpunit** by running `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Also, you can skip tests that need `Arrayable` to be `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable`:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
...
if (!collect() instanceof Arrayable) {
    $skipMessage = <<<'MESSAGE'
This test has conflicts with tightenco/collect and it seems you are using it.
If you are running the testsuite with your global phpunit, please try running 'vendor/bin/phpunit'.
MESSAGE;
    $this->markTestSkipped($skipMessage);
}
```

Comment: By registering a script called test in your composer and calling phpunit, does it use the global or the local one? I know it can find the local even with no global install, but does it prioritize local over global?

What makes no sense to me is the use of `Contracts\Support\Arrayable` without specifying the project name, which causes the conflict. If not a bug, a bad practice.